# Where to clear the requestId from MDC

Tags: java, filter, jax-rs, interceptor, mdc

I'm trying to add a `requestId` to my web app's logs, as shown [here](https://coderwall.com/p/qjwyya/jax-rs-mapped-diagnostic-context-filter).

```
public class MDCFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter
{
    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "client-id";

    @Context
    protected HttpServletRequest r;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext req) throws IOException
    {
        Optional<String> clientId = Optional.fromNullable(r.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For"));
        MDC.put(CLIENT_ID, clientId.or(defaultClientId()));
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext req, ContainerResponseContext resp) throws IOException
    {
        MDC.remove(CLIENT_ID);
    }

    private String defaultClientId()
    {
        return "Direct:" + r.getRemoteAddr();
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that it sets and **removes** `requestId` from `MDC` in the above filter. I also log the bodies of the responses my application generates with a `WriterInterceptor`. The problem is that, since [interceptors run after filters](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9927), by the time my `WriterInterceptor` executes, there is no requestId in `MDC`.

My question is, is it ok to call `MDC.clear()` at the end of `WriterInterceptor` (which feels somehow hacky), or is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: I'm having the exact same question, did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. This is how it currently works in code I'm developing

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public final class RequestFilter implements Filter {
  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
      //stuff
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } finally {
      // this clears a specific entry from the MDC but not the entire MDC
      RequestContext.clear();
    }
  }
}
```

I *could* clear the entire MDC in the finally block here...but I don't know when Spring logs exceptions. Would I be clearing too early? My new plan is to clear the MDC when I start a request.

I'm not sure if this is a full answer, but clearing the MDC in my highest precedence filter should work.